# ICAP "File decompression/decode" error when downloading XML R package

Tags: xml, r, repository, cran

I'm trying to download the XML package for R.

Being a Windows user, and following http://www.omegahat.org/RSXML, I tried the in-line installation :

```
install.packages("XML", repos = "http://www.omegahat.org/R")
```

And got :

```
package ‘XML’ is available as a source package but not as a binary
```

You can indeed browse http://www.omegahat.org/R to see that bin/windows/contrib/2.15/ does not contain XML file, contrary to bin/windows/contrib/2.14/ (binary files, older version of R) or to src/contrib/ (source files).

Now, if I want to download the binary or the source file from my browser (to install it afterwards in R) I have the following error, both on http://www.omegahat.org/R and http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html :

```
ICAP Error (icap_error)
An error occurred while performing an ICAP operation:
File decompression/decode error;
  File:              <name of the file downloaded>;
  Sub File:          <some files>/exampleData/dtd.zip;
  Vendor:            Sophos, Plc.;
  Engine error code: 0xA004021A;
  Engine version:    3.41.0;
  Pattern version:   4.87G.4724528.2257566597;
  Pattern date:      2013/04/05 04:26:00
There could be a network problem,
the ICAP service may be misconfigured,
or the ICAP server may have reported an error.
```

Meanwhile, other packages (binary and source) can be dowloaded easily (such as XMLSchema, from the same Omegahat repository). Any clue? Does any one have the same situation?

I guess it is a error from Omegahat but how comes it is not detected? Who have I to ask for it to be corrected? And how can I dowload a previous but effective version of the package?

Comment: What happens if you download the package zip file and install from RGui (Packages -> Install packages from local zip files...)

Comment: I basically can not download anything related to XML package, neither the binary (zip file) nor the source (tar.gz file) because of the mentionned error. I guess my computer is not the matter, but to confirm I have to know what happens when others try to dowload the same files.